# To open a given URL into div tag of HTML body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a given HTML page, suppose

```
<Html>
       <head>
       </head>
       <body>
          <div id="Test" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></div>
       </body>
```

My Requirement is to open a given URL suppose `https://www.google.com` into that particular div using javascript,keeping the content of head tag or any other div tag intact. Is it possible to do so and if yes how. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use iframe in div tag

Comment: try to use jquery load  - will that work? http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: @jQuery : I don't have the source of HTML. I can only write java script and import my solution to render my URL.

Comment: use this code 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#test').html("<iframe src=https://www.google.com' width='' height='' />");
})

Comment: Does the URL you're trying to load exist on the same domain as your HTML page? That is relevant information. You can't load google.com (or any other page outside your own domain) using Ajax because of cross-origin restrictions, and Google and many other pages prevent iframes as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can inject it into the dom with jquery in 2 ways, firstly using a iframe.

```
$('#Test').html("<iframe src='[your url]' width='' height='' />");
```

This will place the `iframe` holding the content of your page inside your `#test` div without altering the surrounding elements.

The above is a very simplistic way to do it and you'd be much better off (depending on where the iframe'd page is coming from) on using jquery's [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method

```
$("#test").load("somepage.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery function .load() can do the trick.

```
<script language="javascript">
  $(function() {

    $("#Test").load('http://google.com');

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that the above will fail. cross origin request. Unless the OP works at google